# Re-rendering textures with camera.unproject sets wrong positions on camera movement

Tags: java, camera, libgdx

**The problem**

When I move the Camera every texture that is getting rendered flickers about the screen on 2 different positions.

**What I want**

example: When I move the camera to the left, I want the all the textures to move 32 pixels to the right. *camera moves 32 pixels per button press.*

**Current code**

*I added some extra explanation in comments.*

**MainProgramEntryPoint**

```
/**
 * DefaultCamera: Setting up OrthographicCamera
 * CameraMovement: Using camera.translate on keypresses to move the screen.
 * TestMoveable: Creating a texture for testing rendering.
 */
public class WorldSimGame extends ApplicationAdapter {
    private DefaultCamera defaultCamera;
    private CameraMovement cameraMovement;
    private TestMoveable testMoveable;

    // Setting up the camera and texture.
    public void create ()  {
        defaultCamera = new DefaultCamera();
        cameraMovement =  new CameraMovement(defaultCamera.getCamera());
        testMoveable = new TestMoveable();
        testMoveable.create(defaultCamera);
    }

    // The testMoveable.render(defaultCamera) should keep track of the  testMoveable position
    public void render ()  {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        defaultCamera.render();
        testMoveable.render(defaultCamera);
    }
}
```

**TestMoveable**

```
public class TestMoveable {
    private Texture tex;
    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private Vector3 position;

    public void create(DefaultCamera defaultCamera) {
        tex = new Texture(("wall.png"));    
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        position = new Vector3(100, 100, 0);
        defaultCamera.getCamera().unproject(position);
    }
```

> I cant imagine setting the x and y coordinates on the world coordinates wouldn't work.

```
    public void render(DefaultCamera defaultCamera) {       
        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(tex, position.x, position.y);
        batch.end();
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? And is there a better way to implement position checking for the renderers?

Comment: I think you have some miss understanding how Orthographic camera works. Here are some links where it is explained how to work with the Orthographic camera: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Orthographic-camera. Here is a good tutorial: http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2013/11/06/LibGDX-Tutorial-7-Camera-basics.aspx. And maybe this can help you to understand the use of `.unproject`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51993577/libgdxs-world-units/52072708#52072708

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to check the position of the renderer. All what you must do is to set the size and position of your `camera`. Then with `batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined)` you say the batch to draw what the camera sees.

So when you create a camera with size = 50x50 and position = 100,100
and you now create a `Texture` with size = 50x50 and position = 75,75
The Texture will perfectly fit the hole screen.

The position of camera is in the center. So the position of `Texture` is 75,75 and not 100,100

When you now will move your camera, you can use the method: `translate()` of your camera.
Call: `camera.translate(25,0)` to move your camera 25 units to the right and now you only see the half of your `Texture` on the left side of the screen.

This is an easy example of a Moveable camera. You can use the arrow keys to move around:

```
public class WorldSimGame extends ApplicationAdapter {

    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private Texture texture;

    public WorldSimGame() { }

    @Override
    public void create(){
        //Create texture, batch and camera
        texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("badlogic.jpg"));
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        camera = new OrthographicCamera(60,60);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(){
        //clear screen
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        moveCamera();
        //update camera that he recalculate his position and Matrix
        camera.update();

        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined); //set batch to draw what the camera sees
        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(texture,0,0); //draw texture
        batch.end();
    }

    private void moveCamera(){
        //move camera
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.RIGHT)){
            camera.translate(4,0);
        }
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.LEFT)){
            camera.translate(-4,0);
        }
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.UP)){
            camera.translate(0,4);
        }
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.DOWN)){
            camera.translate(0,-4);
        }
    }
}
```